# Are there any alternatives to overriding the 'host' header programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two services I'm running locally on docker images. One of them is an nginx server with configuration to proxy requests to various other services, and the other is a simple React GraphiQL UI.

The nginx server is not explicitly set up to run on localhost, but when making requests with curl/postman I can explicitly set the `host` header to be that of the actual url (rather than `localhost`) and it will then find the correct config and the request will succeed.

The issue is that I would like to call the server from a local instance of my UI, but it's failing because I can't overwrite the `host` header. I've tried to manually add it to my react `fetch` request but when I check the request in the browser the header isn't there. After some searching I then found some slack posts saying it's not possible, although no references to why.

```
return fetch(
        edgeUrl(environment) + "/some/endpoint",
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getApiKey(partner, environment),
                'host': 'actual.host.com',
                'origin': 'http://localhost/'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ query })
        }
    )
```

Is there any other way to override the host used in requests? Possibly another http library I could use? I'd prefer not to have to configure the nginx server for localhost as it is owned by another team.

Comment: Why would Host be different from what `edgeUrl(environment)` resolves to?

Comment: @AndréSnede The server is running on localhost, but in the configuration localhost isn't specified as a host. By setting the 'host' header manually on requests it uses the configuration for that host instead of localhost.

Comment: You shouldn't fiddle with the host header. And I am glad that you are blocked from it. Change your host file, to add actual.host.com as pointing to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @AndréSnede Why not? I was told by a coworker on the team who owns this service to just override the host header for using it locally so I need some sort of reason besides "a stranger on the internet told me not to" to go back to them and say I can't do that.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on a stranger on the internet I agree, you should do your own research. The browser simply doesn't allow you to. It is also wrong, you are not talking to the host you claim. It is actually a very common penetration testing attack, where you spoof the header, so it is good that it is not allowed in the browser.

You should change the host file, to point the domain you want to that specific IP, so that you browser knows it is the origin of the website. For security reasons, CORS reasons.

Comment: Besides, it takes 2 minutes to do it right. And so much longer to do it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested here's some information on possible attacks using the host header and why it's useful to validate it, which is what this service is doing.

https://portswigger.net/web-security/host-header

https://infosecwriteups.com/identifying-escalating-http-host-header-injection-attacks-7586d0ff2c67

I'm going to ask the other team if I can add localhost configuration to their nginx config so that I can make requests locally, looks like my coworker was misinformed in suggesting I override the host header.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try change the host header. The browser won't allow you to, and it's not the right way to do it.

As I see it, you have 2 options:

1. Configure NGINX to accept requests to localhost, if that is its' actually hostname.
2. Change the hosts file, to include your domain to point to 127.0.0.1, which is equivalent to adding it to DNS.

The Windows Hosts file is located here: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

You should add the following to your hosts file after the comments `#`.

```
actual.host.com 127.0.0.1
```